How to extract transformation parameter from opencv estimate2d of warped and cropped image
I'm trying to extract the Translation and Rotation parameter of my opencvs estimateAffine2D result, for image registration evaluation.
I have an 1024x1024px image from which I crop out a 512x512px center patch.
This is patch is my reference image.
Than I create my moving image as follows:

Rotate the original 1024x1024 image.
Translate the image in X and Y direction.
Crop out again a 512x512px center patch.

Then I have my two images for registration providng the keypoints for the estimateAffine2D function.
The Estimation works fine, I visually checked by transforming the moving image with the estimated transformation matrix.
Besides visual checking I need to compare the Result to the Original Parameter i used to transform the image.
I dont know how to gain the equivalent parameters from the result matrix.
I just need to calculate the parameter error of overlapping rotating image patches, matched by the registration algorithm. If you have any other approach which helps me gets this I would be very happy.
Thank You :)
I tried different matrix operations, rotating around different points and other stuff that I truly don't understand. But couldnt get it to Work.
The Parameter gained by the estimation always differ significantly from the input parameter, except when I start the transformation at the already cropped image, but then I get large empty tiles at the edges from the transformation.
EDIT Example:
Example Workflow to get the Idea
I transform the Original image with the following code snippet, and I tried to alter the order of the translation/rotation and change the rotation center:
def translate_rotate_image(image, translation, angle):
    w, h = image.size
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w//2, h//2), angle, 1.0)

    M[0, 2] += translation[0]
    M[1, 2] += translation[1]  
    
    img_array = cv2.warpAffine(np.array(image),M, (w,h))

    return  Image.fromarray(img_array)

After I cropped a the center of the original and the transformed image, i put them in an image registration pipeline resulting in target and reference points to calculate a transformation matrix:
affine_matrix,_ = cv2.estimateAffine2D(target_pts,ref_pts)
affine_matrix_invert = cv2.invertAffineTransform(affine_matrix)

The affine Matrix works fine to transform the cropped image to one another. But I need to compare the original matrix M or the input parameter translation and rotation to the affine_matrix to evaluate the registration perfomance.
For rotation: 15degree, Translation = (-150,50)
I get the following matrices:
M = [ 9.65925826e-01  2.58819045e-01 -3.80363493e+02]
    [-2.58819045e-01  9.65925826e-01  3.50215549e+02]
affine_matrix = [   0.96610422    0.25865762 -207.62508698]
                [  -0.25884415    0.96573068  125.0849814 ]

inverted_affine = [  0.96578042  -0.25867094 232.87609314]
                  [  0.25885748   0.96615398 -67.10604652]


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

uh what? you have an affine matrix, right? and what's the specific hurdle you need help with? can you present an example? not a hypothetical or text. numbers, pictures, data.

ok so you want to compare affine matrices. great. you can either do that by analyzing the elements of the matrices (compare the 2x3 scaling/rotation part, compare the translation part) or you can map a set of relevant source points (say the corners of the source) using both, and then compare how far apart the mapped points are.

Thanks for the idea with mapping of the corner points.
Is there a way to extract the parameter from the affine matrix in a way to compare it with the inital 15° and -150,50 translation?

typo, I meant to write 2x2 there. -- you chained several transforms, in some order I don't know. you need to compose those too. I assumed you did, so you'd have the reference affine matrix. the affine matrix represents a rotation followed by a translation. if you wanted to rotate around a point, you would need to translate, rotate, translate back. order of transforms matters.
